# What are the recommended over-sampling or under-sampling techniques to handle multi-class imbalanced datasets for machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, multi-class, oversampling

Many techniques are for two-class classification. What is the recommended techniques to over- or under-sample multi-class datasets?

Comment: Possibly relevant, especially if you can offer an answer: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem