# Precision and Recall are very less

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, lasso, confusion-matrix

The model has a problem in predicting since the data was not balanced first I used SMOTE for balancing. I have used some other techniques to balance the data like under sampling and performing upper and under sampling together. But the results are almost same. I have selected features using PCA.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
lr=LogisticRegression(penalty='l1',solver='liblinear',warm_start=True,random_state=109,C=0.9)
lr.fit(xtrain_sm,ytrain_sm)
pred_lr=lr.predict(pca_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix,classification_report
accuracy_lr=round((accuracy_score(ytest,pred_lr)*100),2)
print("accuracy : {}".format(accuracy_lr))
```

This is my classification report :
classification_report

```
     precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.92      0.61      0.73     17281
           1       0.15      0.58      0.24      2079

    accuracy                           0.61     19360
   macro avg       0.54      0.59      0.49     19360
weighted avg       0.84      0.61      0.68     19360
```

Second thing I tried was to use Lasso Regression for feature selection but the results are not good.

```
over=SMOTE(sampling_strategy=0.97)
under=RandomUnderSampler(sampling_strategy=0.99)
steps = [('o', over), ('u', under)]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)
xsmote,ysmote=pipeline.fit_resample(xtrain_select,ytrain)
counter = Counter(y_smote)
print("value after applying SMOTE")
print(counter)
```

Result of Random forest:

```
    precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.89      1.00      0.94     25915
           1       0.38      0.02      0.04      3125

    accuracy                           0.89     29040
   macro avg       0.64      0.51      0.49     29040
weighted avg       0.84      0.89      0.84     29040
```

Can someone suggest me how to proceed with the issue? Also the diagonal values of confusion matrix are not high.

```
array([[25803,   112],
       [ 3061,    64]])
```

Comment: Some related reading (1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models and (2) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247871/what-is-the-root-cause-of-the-class-imbalance-problem

Comment: (3) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he