# GridSearchCV returns unrealistic AUC score with Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, cross-validation

Long time lurker but I've just created an account because its the first time one of my questions has not actually been answered.

I'm currently struggling with optimizing the hyperparameters of a Logistic Regression using GridSearchCV. My current model is severely overfitting (ROC AUC train = 0.93, ROC AUC test = 0.54).

When performing GridSearchCV (on the train set), all the ROC values are > 0.9 and the final ROC is 0.96, as if the score was calculated from the train split. Here is the code :

```
#Define a list of hyperparameters we want to tune
parameters = {
    'log_r__penalty' : ['l1','l2'], 
    'log_r__C'       : np.logspace(-3,3,7),
    'log_r__solver'  : ['saga','lbfgs'],
}

#Defining our LogR pipeline
pipe_lr = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), 
                    ('log_r', LogisticRegression(max_iter = 1000))])

#Defining our Grid Search operator
clf = GridSearchCV(pipe_lr, 
                   param_grid = parameters,
                   scoring = 'roc_auc', 
                   cv = 5,
                   n_jobs=-1,
                  verbose=10)
#Apply our Grid Search operator to our train set
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)

print("tuned hpyerparameters :(best parameters) ",clf.best_params_)
print("ROC AUC :",clf.best_score_)
```

The ROC values are also very similar for all splits even when the hyperparameters are widely changing. Here is an extract of my cv_results_ :

[image: GridSearchCV results]

When I apply this model to my validation set the ROC falls back to 0.56.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but the initial dataset is widely unbalanced (92% / 8%) so I performed ADASYN oversampling to bring back our ratio to 50/50. So in that case X_train has been oversampled while (obviously) the validation and test sets haven't.

Am I missing something here? I feel like GridSearchCV completely fails to optimize my model.

Should I apply GridSearchCV before oversampling?

Comment: It is possible to over-fit the cross-validation estimate as well https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume11/cawley10a/cawley10a.pdf if you tune the hyper-parameters too aggressively

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DikranMarsupial but why would this happen only to Logistic Regression and not when applying the same algorithm to other models like RidgeClassifier? Also forgot to mention in my initial post but edited since that I performed ADASYN oversampling before using the GridSearchCV tuning. But I don't think this should make a difference

Comment: difficult to say - if the dataset is very small, then the imbalance means there are very few positive patterns, in which case the performance statistic may be very noisy, but it is difficult to think of a reason why that should affect LR more than, say ridgeClassifier,

Comment: My thoughts exactly. The dataset isn't that small there are 300k samples in total and I took 10% for test and validation so train is at 240k and test and validation at 30k.

Comment: In that case the imbalance probably isn't an issue.

Comment: @DikranMarsupial: but the oversampling *outside* the CV loop may very well be...

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX yes, indeed!  I don't think LR is going to have a problem with the imbalance, so using ADASYN is (at best) introducing something to go wrong, and as you suggest it needs to be done individually in each fold to avoid bias.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Just an update, I have put my oversampler in a pipeline and observed similar results. I have done a manual cross validation of the oversampling ratio and there is a linear imporvement in ROC AUC the more I oversample, but Gridsearch CV gives me a 0.2 ratio as the optimal. When putting this in my model, ROC AUC falls from 0.7 to 0.51... I have uploaded the code here for reference (I have removed the oversampling gridsearch since it is illogical) : https://www.kaggle.com/octaveati/home-credit-scoring

Answer (score 1):

> the initial dataset is widely unbalanced (92% / 8%) so I performed ADASYN oversampling to bring back our ratio to 50/50. So in that case X_train has been oversampled while (obviously) the validation and test sets haven't.

This may very well be (part of) the reason.

*If* you do oversampling (which you may want to reconsider: [What is the root cause of the class imbalance problem?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/247871/4598), [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/4598)), you crucially need to do that inside the CV. It cannot be "pulled out" before the CV loop, since that creates a leak between the inner (optimization) CV training and test sets.

Also double-check that you do not have any other preprocessing steps that create such leaks: everything from the first pre-processing step that involves computations on more than one case/row (mean centering, variance scaling, ...) on must be done inside the CV loop.

Comment: +1 The way I think of it is that CV is estimating the performance of a *method* for fitting a model, rather than the model itself, so if ADASYN is part of that method, it needs to be performed independently in each fold.

Comment: Thanks for this insightful answer. I think this explains the difference between the manual K-fold CV I did (by applying all my feature selection / data imputation / oversampling functions to each split) and the GridSearch. But then it makes GridSearchCV very difficult to implement, to be honest I don't even know how to add my custom data_imputation function to the pipeline for example...

Comment: Making your imputation function a transformer and use that in the Pipeline is indeed the solution if you want to impute/oversample. Still, please read up the linked threads, in my experience, class imbalance is rarely (if ever) the actual problem. What are typically referred to as "class imbalance problems" are typically problems due to bad choice of algorithm (e.g. binary/discriminative classifier where one-class classifier/class-models would be appropriate for the application), decisions threshold, and/or loss function. You should get those right, whether you then still impute or not.

Comment: Thanks again for your precious insight. Even if balancing the classes may not be necessary, wouldn't it be worth it to include it in gridsearch as a hyperparameter to make sure that I have the best model?   But regardless I have a few NA values I want to apply data imputation on so I guess I will rewrite my data imputation function as a Transformer that can be used within a pipeline

Comment: Just wanted to provide a follow up. I have tried to not oversample and plotted the ROC AUC for each oversampling ratio (from not oversampled to 1), and it appears that the ROC AUC score and my model improves linearly with the oversampling ratio. When I do not do any oversampling, I have a ROC AUC test of 0.51 (0.95 on the train set so a clear overfit) while with a 1.0 oversampling ratio it goes up to 0.69 for both the test and train sets. I have uploaded the code here for reference : https://www.kaggle.com/octaveati/home-credit-scoring